# Flutter Android App update /data problem using Android emulator

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

I seem to have a problem updating my app for Android when I use an Android emulator (same issue with both the Android Studio emulator and Genymotion).
I am using MacOS Ventura (13.6), VSCode (1.82.2) and Flutter 3.13.x (now 3.13.6)

What is happening is that when I build a new version of my app and debug it using an Android emulator my App thinks it is a new install as there is no data there from the previous app version but if I stop that session and start to debug the previous version then it carries on with the data it had when I last ran it.
This never used to happen so something has changed to cause this and I seem to be unable to find out why, especially as this does **not** happen when I do this for my app on iOS using Xcode Simulators.

I don't have access to a real Android device so don't know if the same thing happens there but I am obviously reluctant to release an update for my Android testers unless I can be sure they will be able to carry on from where they were with the previous version.

Has anyone seen this before and/or know what's wrong and/or how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Les.